# Grounding adviseable on tube pre-amp powered by a 9VAC power brick?

Tags: power-supply, noise, grounding, preamp

I have an ART Tube MP pre-amp that is powered by a compact but rather heavy power "brick" that delivers 9V AC @ 1A. I use the pre-amp with a large-diaphragm microphone that gets its 48V phantom power from the pre-amp.

I'm getting an annoying background noise with a low-frequency repetitive component superimposed which obliges me to keep the input and output (tube) gain pots lower than I'd like (at 12h and 9h respectively). Two samples (also with both gains maxed out):
https://soundcloud.com/rjvb/sets/noise-from-the-art-tube-mp-pre-amp

I already looked for a quality PSU, but the only lab-style unit I found that does AC output was worth 6x the price of the pre-amp. Reading more user feedback on this and a comparable Behringer amp I picked up a suggestion to try grounding the set-up.

I know that amplifiers usually have their chassis connected to the mains ground wire (which is then also used to ground the turntable). I thus suppose that running a grounded wire to the pre-amp's metal chassis should thus a priori be safe ... but I prefer to be sure and also get some educated opinions whether this could indeed solve my issue?

I also read an evaluation in which someone claims that running the output through a D.I. got rid of the noise. He never answered the question which D.I. he used...

Another observation: there must be a few big capacitors in the system. The unit's power LED remains on for quite a while after putting off the mains power to the PSU, and the mic continues to receive enough phantom power to give off a signal after turning off the phantom power on the unit. It seems to me that that points to the presence of a couple of aggressive lowpass filters which might even remove the need for a line filter?

Noise wave form with auto-trigger. The waveform being triggered on must be the "prrrffftt" sound and is pretty constant. If I'm not mistaken it occurs at a 10ms interval, which seems much faster that what I hear (but I may be hearing a "beat" of course).
[image: noise wave form with auto-trigger]

FFT spectrum. Contrary to what I mentioned elsewhere I now get a peak at 50Hz systematically, it's even what my tuner app gives. Strangely enough I don't hear the "mains hum" I'm used to hear from an ungrounded turntable pickup...
[image: Spectrum]

Comment: If it isn't safe there's something extremely wrong with that preamp.

Comment: Yes, it could indeed solve your issue. However, there is also the issue of ground loops. Ground connections should form a "tree" topology. That is, don't connect ground wires in a loop. That makes a giant inductive coil (giant physically, not inductively)  which may pick up noise from your AC lines. You probably already do this, but you should also use twisted pair or co-ax cable for any audio lines to reduce noise pickup. (But that is where ground loops often arise. People mistakenly ground both ends of a coax, and both chassis's to the utility ground.

Comment: What does the 9 VAC connect to in your system? It could also be noise on your house wiring. You may need to filter the 9 VAC.

Comment: Yes, all cables ought to be coax (but only the mic cable should matter here, given that the noise depends on the amp gain settings). My set-up is simple enough that I'd only run a single wire from the mains ground to the pre-amp chassis, no loops there that I can think of.

Comment: @BrianDrummond - why do you think something is extremely wrong with the pre-amp?

Comment: @Mattman944 - I've been wondering about that. The wiring in question runs along a long Cat5 (or Cat6) ethernet cable, but that one is transparent so I can confirm it's shielded and I wouldn't expect it to cary a signal likely to affect a 230V@60Hz power supply. I'll test the set-up in other parts of the house that do have recent cabling. Any suggestions on how to filter the 9VAC?

Comment: This should work on either the 120VAC or 9 VAC side. It will need a solid ground to be effective. https://www.amazon.com/CW4E-30A-S-Noise-Suppressor-Power-Filter/dp/B07PFDS5J8

Comment: @BrianDrummond - indeed you did, sorry, somehow I missed the 1st word in your answer

Comment: @Mattman944 - that's a whole lot cheaper than the 120€ weird dongle that you put either before or after the PS in a multi-socket outlet. I understand you have no direct experience with it? On Amazon.fr (where I'd buy) about half the reviews say the thing doesn't do anything. I also saw I should check with the CPL gadgets removed from the circuit (but I think I already had the noise before installing those).

Comment: Well - grounding the pre-amp chassis had no effect, nor did removing the multi-socket extender that has one of those switches with a neon indicator light, nor did removing both CPL terminals from the circuit. Idem disconnecting the mic. I have now noticed that the white noise component comes from the input step (a solid-state circuit AFAIK) while the "prrrrrffft" component comes clearly from the output circuit (the lamp). I wonder if this component could come from the voltage step-up, assuming the tube is indeed powered with the usual high voltage?

Comment: Can you record the noise and share a file?

Comment: No, I have not used the filter that I referenced. However, it is basically what a typical engineer would design, a common mode choke and caps to ground. To determine the effectiveness of the filter, the noise components would need to be known.

Comment: I put 2 quick sample recordings on soundcloud; link is in the original post.

Comment: [This person disassembled a pre-amp like yours.](https://soundmaster.ua/media/blfa_files/ART_Tube_MP_Modification.pdf)  It has no voltage regulation at all that I can see, and nothing but capacitors for cleaning up the DC.  It appears to generate high voltage for the tube using a voltage multiplier.

Comment: You might want to check all those electrolytic capacitors to see if any have gone bad.

Comment: They would have had to be bad from the start, and that means I could just as well send it in - should still be under warranty.

Comment: It bugs me a bit that there are almost no single or multisocket adapters with a built-in EMI/RFI filter (I found only 2 on amazon.fr, both with negative feedback about their filtering capacities, same btw for the crazy expensive hifi multisocket adapters!)

Comment: I ended up ordering a pre-cabled filter (https://www.audiophonics.fr/fr/filtres-secteur/filtre-secteur-emi-rfi-230v-3a-avec-cables-p-11627.html) which I can just complete with a male 3-prong plug and a female 2-prong to receive the PSU - plus some copper tape to shield the output. We'll see what difference that makes. Next step would be to try this: http://f4haj.net/2012/09/30/filtre-secteur/ - could be handy to have around anyway (but with a metal enclosure and shielded output cable if I can find one).

Answer (score 0):

The PSU does not need to be grounded, it is intended to be AC to avoid ground loops (if it is grounded then that is an opportunity for conducted noise along the ground to interfere with the audio setup.

The amp should have filtering to reject noise on it's power input, if it doesn't then there are probably better options than getting a new PSU.
One of these things would be to use a line filter to filter out anything but the fundamental frequency.

Another thing would be to make sure the noise isn't coming from other sources in your audio system, and make sure it is the power source. Ferrites on cables could cut back on high frequency noise if the source is something like cellphone radiation.

Comment: Thanks! Please see my latest comment to my original question above, I think I was writing it when your answer came in.

Comment: FWIW, I fed the output signal into a good iOS tuning app, which picked up the low-frequency component. Some aliasing going on of course (I've seen it indicate values between 15Hz and 26Hz) but I think we're talking about a 20Hz signal here. And it gets drowned out when I activate the +20dB feature on the input side, but then I can barely use the tube stage at all (mic must give too strong a signal)

Comment: About those ferrites: I see they're sold by the bunch, is that because you'd have to clip as many as it takes to protect the entire cable length? Or is it enough to put one just before the plug that goes into the device, as you see on so many PSU cables (but indeed NOT on the cable of this PSU)?

Comment: I put the PSU on the protected outputs of one of my Eaton UPS; turns out the noise gets much worse when I disconnect the UPS from the mains. But, disconnecting both from the mains (and feeding the ART directly from the mains) does NOT solve the issue, so the UPS are not the source of pollution on my circuit.

Comment: Now one thing that's really weird is that I decided to test the ART's jack output, and it turned out there was negligible noise there. Thinking the XLR->3.5TRRS output cable might be bad I went back to that, and also got negligible noise. For a while at least. Looks like I'm going to have to invest in a proper 6.35 -> 3.5 mic cable... and maybe contact Amazon (where I bought the ART) to see how they propose an exchange might be implemented. (Or just order a 2nd unit and send it back because of noise if it isn't any better.)

Comment: You only need one to block HF signals, I would put the signal into an oscilloscope app and monitor all of the frequencies. 20Hz would be a weird signal to pickup, I would think more of 60Hz and above would be a problem

Comment: 1 ferrite you mean, I presume? I ordered some, if that can remove the need to shield the entire length of cable then I'm in and I'll think differently about what I've always found to be cumbersome obstacles...

Comment: I added 1 ferrite on the 9VAC cable, didn’t make any (audible) difference.